# How to handle dynamic data model in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, datamodel

In the application I am currently working on, there is a portion in which I do not know the db schema as it is defined by the users and tables are generated dynamically.

The application is  being done is ASP.Net MVC 3 and SQL Server 2008 R2. For such an application what would you suggest to use for data objects and data access layer.

One option is to simply return datatables from DAL and use them. but they would be untyped.
The option would be to create objects dynamically from resultset. but it would not perform very well.

Is there any other way? Entity Framework's Code First could be helpful? What about Expando objects?

One thing very important is that the application is very data extensive, something like GBs of data.

Comment: What do the users expect to do with those unknown data structures? Or is the logical structure of the data known, and only the database schema can be different for different users?

Answer (score 0):

Application where tables are created dynamically by users is not scenario for Entity Framework. Entity framework requires compiled classes mapped to tables (+ mapping if not inferred by conventions) and your code must use these classes to take advantage of them.

In my opinion application where tables are created dynamically is not something where you can expect strongly typed access or great performance. Both these requirements expect that you write a code against well defined set of classes (defined at design time) and you optimize the code and data access for these classes. In your scenario this is not possible - use untyped datasets and dynamically created SQL + ASP.NET data bound controls and hope that it will work in most cases.

Edit:

Now I see that you want to use MVC3 = no data bound controls. You will have to write a code inspecting your untyped datasets and producing some UI to allow viewing, editing and validating the data with structure you don't know upfront. That generally means that you need your own meta model describing newly created tables, constrains, field sizes, nullable columns etc. and use this information to create UI and perhaps also prepare untyped datasets from that information.